# Botão adicionar o app na tela inicial

Tags: android

Ultimamente ando vendo esse botão que está no rodapé da print `Adicionar o app QuintoAndar à tela inicial` presente em alguns sites, quando você clica ele adicionar um icone do site no menu e na tela inicial do android, gostaria de saber se alguém sabe como faz isso, procurei na internet e não achei nada.

O site em questão da print é o da Startup QuintoAndar: https://www.quintoandar.com.br se alguém quiser ver esse é o link.

Gostaria de adicionar isso em meus sistemas porém como eu disse não achei nenhuma informação, se alguém souber como faz isso ou puder me indicar onde procurar ficarei muito grato! Desde já obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não estou conseguindo responder a pergunta. Porém essa funcionalidade é chamada de A2HS ou "Adicionar à tela inicial". 
Basicamente, você precisa incluir o arquivo de manifesto do aplicativo web no site com detalhes sobre o aplicativo e o Chrome faz todo o trabalho duro.  Veja mais aqui na documentação: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/?hl=en

Comment: Obrigado mesmo @LeonardoAssunção vai me ajudar muito.